# Device identifier in Android

Tags: android, serial-number

When I debug an application in Android on my xperia, I see something similar in console output window:

```
[2012-02-25 22:51:20 - App] Automatic Target Mode: using device '4258393032524D395735'
[2012-02-25 22:51:20 - App] Uploading App.apk onto device '4258393032524D395735'
```

Does anybody know where the value '4258393032524D395735' come from? This value looks like some serial number of the device (but not `ro.serialno`), which survive Factory reset and that's exactly what I need. `ANDROID_ID` changes after Factory reset on Xperia.

This value does not correspond to `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()`.

`ro.serialno` (from SystemProperties) is empty string on that Xperia mini pro.

I have also second device (HTC) and there this value IS from ro.serialno.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is `android.os.Build.SERIAL`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. The value of android.os.Build.SERIAL is "unknown"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact use case is, but you *may* not want that identifier. There's an post on the Android Dev Blog that covers this situation (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) and recommends against it. There are also a couple hundred thousand devices with the same "unique" ID.

There's just too much fragmentation in Android for you to get a simple value, I suggest having a method to determine this value with fallbacks based on platform version, etc.

Why do you need something that persists between device resets?

Comment: I'm selling my app via premium SMS, I construct a code based on some unique device id, send a hash to my sms gateway and answer with another hash, which then activates my application. Many users complain, that after factory reset the code is useless and they have to send another SMS. The value ANDROID_ID persists device reset only when ro.serialno is some value.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to Settings->About->Status->Serial number that is the android.os.Build.SERIAL and it comes from System / Environment properties : ro.serialno

There is also a Secure.Android_ID and a TelephonyManager.getDeviceID()

And there are others too, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853253/529543)